# Attribute to configurable product

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, configurable-product

I'm trying to add custom field in my products, "bra_size".

I'm able to add it in magento, make associated_item with it, but impossible to get the value of this product in the associated_products array of the products.

When I make a "http://magento.xxx.com/api/catalog/get_product.php?productId=xx" on the configurable product, I get this :

```
configitems: {
Bra Size: {
79: "95 D",
80: "95 C",
83: "90 D",
84: "90 C",
88: "85 D",
89: "85 C"
}
```

But in the associated_products array, "brasize" don't appear :

```
{
product_id: "1259",
type_id: "simple",
inventory: "0.0000",
sku: "TRD01-92173-85 C",
weight: "0.1500",
news_from_date: null,
news_to_date: null,
status: "1",
visibility: "4",
created_at: "2014-06-17 11:27:39",
updated_at: "2014-06-17 11:28:02",
custom_smartid: null,
custom_color: null,
custom_pantsize: null,
custom_shoesize: null,
custom_shirtsize: null,
custom_uniquesize: null,
price: 17.95
},
```

I also kmow that magento save the value of braSize in the simple product, but still don't able to catch it from the configurable product.
Does anyone know how to fix it ?
Thank's a lot ;)

EDIT :
Yep, I rebuild all indexes, reboot server, but just use Magento to add attribute (no php or module or other)
Here is the get_product.php :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/Init.php';

$task = new Init(__FILE__);

try {
    $client = $task->getSOAPClient();
    $session = $task->getSOAPSession($client);

    $productId = $_GET['productId'];

    $result[0] = array('catalog_product.information', $productId);
    $result[1] = array('catalog_product_attribute_media.list', $productId);

    $list = $client->multiCall($session, $result);

    $task->setResponse($list);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $task->errorResponse($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Did you rebuild the indexes? also, can you post the code from `get_product.php`?

Comment: Edit my question, too much character for a comment

Answer (score 1):

When you call `catalog_product.information` you can pass in the attributes that you want to return. I think for your code the following will work.

```
$result[0] = array('catalog_product.information', $productId, null, array(all attributes you want));
```

If you are using the newer api the code looks as follows:

```
// product info
$attributes = new stdclass();
$attributes->attributes = array('product_title', 'description', 'short_description', 'price');
$list = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, <sku>, NULL, $attributes);
```

Comment: So I add null, array(attributes), replacing attributes by the name of my custom attribute "bra_size" ? Or do I have to find a attribute code, or something like it ?
Thank's for your time =)

Comment: sorry you just need to add an array of attribute codes.

Comment: Thank's, try it when I find the attribute code, and when I got access to the php files. But I will update if this work for me, don't worry

Comment: Okay so I replace the line by "$result[0] = array('catalog_product.information', $productId, null, array('zdl_brasize'));", where 'zdl_brasize' is the attribute code, but no difference in the function =/. I also try removing 'null', but can't see any difference in the result of the operation